# Fuzzy Logic Implementation In Android

Tags: fuzzy-logic

How to add jfuzzy lite library in android?

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: i have done and i found www.fuzzylite.com site which is quite helpful. I had download sources from their but got confuse how to import that in Android Studio and use that resource for my application

Comment: yes, i have successfully completed my android application. if anybody need help please be free to contact me...

Comment: glad to hear that. you could post an answer to your own question to share what you have learned :)

Comment: What library did you use? Jfuzzylogic seems to be incompatable with android studio and jfuzzylite is hard to get a single output from (on intellij).

Comment: Better use Fuzzy Class as i do  in this address: https://github.com/susylPearl/RNA/blob/RNA/app/src/main/java/com/example/sushil/androidmaterialtest/MyFuzzyClass.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anybody who feels problem in implementing Fuzzy Library in Android can easily view my project in Git address which i mentioned here:
https://github.com/susylPearl/RNA

For successfully completion of the project follow below steps:

1. Download Fuzzylite library from www.fuzzylite.com/downloads
2. After then import it in your project as it is jar file.
3. Then make assets folder and inside it create file with .fcl extension and     copy .fcl code for your project, you can view mine here: https://github.com/susylPearl/RNA/blob/RNA/app/src/main/assets/tipper.fcl
4. After that you should develop your ideas and develop code as same like me and complete your project successfully. If any suggestion comment me. Thanks.