# Fuzzy logic on Android application

Tags: java, android, fuzzy-logic, jfuzzylogic

I want to use the Fuzzy logic in my android application. I proceed with trying the jFuzzyLogic library (http://jfuzzylogic.sourceforge.net/html/index.html) and the example provided on eclipse.
In the execution of the example, I have confronted 2 problems:

1. The functions: `fis.getVariable(fileName).chart()` and `fis.getVariable("tip").chartDefuzzifier(true)` are not supported.
2. the application can't read the FCL file.

Can you help to solve this problem or give me another example of android application that is based on Fuzzy logic?

Comment: AFAIK jFuzzyLogic uses jFreeChart to display (.chart..()-Methodes) the graphs, which works with swing, so you will have problems using that in android.  
For the FCL-File: If the FIS-Object ends up beeing null, without an exception thrown it probably can't find the file. But I guess you can find out more by debugging into FIS.load(...). what example are you using? link?

Comment: I used this example: [link](http://jfuzzylogic.sourceforge.net/html/example_java.html) I added this class to my android project. The problem is the output fis = FIS.load(fileName,true)  is always null

Comment: Then it does not find the fcl-file. Do you have it in a folder called fcl in the project? Do you already have an Android Project? If yes, maybe you need to put the file in your assets and load the InputStream via the AssetManager [link](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-read-file-from-assets/)? You can call `FIS load(InputStream inputStream, boolean verbose)` with the input stream you got from the Assetsmanager. But i dont know much about android development, so i could be totaly of here

Comment: you can probably find your solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369203/fuzzy-logic-implementation-in-android