# Fuzzy searching in android

Tags: java, android, database, search, libraries

[Fuzzy Logic Implementation In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369203/fuzzy-logic-implementation-in-android)
After I imported the `jfuzzylite` jar file as lib into my project I am getting error like this:

> Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration
>   ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>
> Failed to transform file 'jFuzzyLogic.jar' to match attributes
>   {artifactType=android-classes} using transform JarTransform Transform
>   output file
>   C:\Users\Sushil\AndroidstudioProjects\AndroidMaterialTest\libs\jFuzzyLogic.jar
>   does not exist

Comment: Please include your build.gradle file contents.

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: in the question - not in the comments

Comment: you need to include the app build.gradle contents