# FCL Implementation Android Studio

Tags: android, fuzzy, fcl

I have followed this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369203/fuzzy-logic-implementation-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com) but when i am importing

```
import net.sourceforge.jFuzzyLogic.FIS;
```

it gives me error can't find symbol net i am stuck kindly help me out
Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhhbG.png)/questions/31369203/fuzzy-logic-implementation-in-android

Comment: You might missed: "After then import it in your project as it is jar file." (which is described in the link you posted)

Comment: no i added jar in lib directory by going to project structure
i have to submit this i have completed my other project just stuck over ther

Comment: yes thanks it solved library name was different Thanks